# How to move spaces after or before certain tags

Tags: javascript

I use Quill.js editor for editing text, I have bold and italic button but the problem that I need to transform html to markdown. For correct markdown I need that there are no spaces before or after strong or em tag, the best place I think will be to move spaces in html string
For example
`let html =  '<p><strong>some </strong><em>text</em> <strong>is      </strong><em>here</em></p>';`
The result must be
`let html =  '<p><strong>some</strong> <em>text</em> <strong>is</strong> <em>here</em></p>';`
The space before close tag  is moved after 
How can I achive this result?

I try to split string for spaces and there get first tags but I can't finish because I think I need some regExp

```
`const tags = ['strong', 'em']
 let newHtml = ''

 tags.forEach(tag => {
  let splitOnMarker = html.split(' ')
 })

let result = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  item = item.replace(/(<\/strong>).*/, '</strong> ');
  acc += item;
  return acc;
}, '');`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a simple replacement like so:

```js
let html = '<p><strong>some </strong><em>text</em> <strong>is </strong><em>here</em></p>';
    console.log(html);
    html = html.replace(/ <\/strong>/g, '</strong> ');
    html = html.replace(/ <\/em>/g, '</em> ');
    html = html.replace(/<strong> /g, ' <strong>');
    html = html.replace(/<em> /g, ' <em>');
    console.log(html);
```

Comment: This script work correct if space before close tag but It has to work if space is at the begining for example <p>some<strong> text</strong></p> -> <p>some <strong>text</strong></p> The space is moved from strong tag and set after word 'some'

Comment: I edited the post to account for the other cases you mentioned.

Comment: Work for all cases good exapt for multiple spaces for example <p><em>{here 5 spaces}text</em></p>

Answer (score 0):

You could use some regExp like this :

```
const html = '<p><strong>some</strong><em> text</em><strong>is</strong><em> here</em></p>';

// Replace spaces before and after strong and em tags
const markdown = html.replace(/(<(?:strong|em)>)\s+/g, '$1').replace(/\s+(<\/(?:strong|em)>)/g, '$1').replace(/(<(?:strong|em)>)\s+/g, '$1').replace(/\s+(<em>)/g, '$1');

console.log(markdown); // '<p><strong>some</strong> <em>text</em> <strong>is</strong> <em>here</em></p>'
```

Comment: It works correct with space before close tag but not the case when at the start:
let html = '<p><strong>some</strong><em> text</em><strong>is</strong><em>   here</em></p>';  -> '<p><strong>some</strong> <em>text</em><strong>is</strong> <em>here</em></p>' - space after open <em> must move before <em> tag

Comment: I've edited my answer so that your case is also treated